# ASP.NET form using label

Tags: asp.net, forms, label

I have to create an asp.net form using label. I found an example for this task and tried to run it but nothing from the expected result appeared. Do you have any idea what else should be done to run it? (I'm still at the very beginnig of asp.net.)
Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" %>
<script runat="server">
Sub submit(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
label1.Text=txt1.Text
End Sub
</script>
<html>
<body>
<form runat="server">
Write some text:
<asp:TextBox id="txt1" Width="200" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button id="b1" Text="Copy to Label" OnClick="submit" runat="server"/>
<p><asp:Label id="label1" runat="server"/></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Off topic remark: try and get into the habit of using descriptive names for the labels, textboxes etc. else you wind up with `label1` through `label20` and it becomes difficult to remember what's what.

Answer (score 4):

Please check the default access modifier for your function(SUB).

In c# we use protected and from **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)**

> Class members, including nested classes and structs, can be public,
>   protected internal, protected, internal, or private. The access level
>   for class members and struct members, including nested classes and
>   structs, is private by default. Private nested types are not
>   accessible from outside the containing type.

So try with Friend access modifier for VB.Net.